# Casting to derived class from base class throws exception

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, dynamic-cast, static-cast

I have 3 inheritance classes: `Base` -> `Intermediate` -> `Derived`.

Why did it throw an exception when I used `dynamic_cast`?

```
class Base { ... };
class Intermediate : public Base { ... };
class Derived : public Intermediate { ... };

Base* base = new Derived();

// No throw
auto intermediate = static_cast<Intermediate *>(base);
auto derived1 = static_cast<Derived *>(base);
auto derived2 = static_cast<Derived *>(intermediate);

// All throw
// (vcruntime140d.dll): Access violation reading location [...].
auto intermediate = dynamic_cast<Intermediate *>(base);
auto derived1 = dynamic_cast<Derived *>(base);
auto derived2 = dynamic_cast<Derived *>(intermediate);
```

Comment: `base` is of type `Derived`

Comment: and arrows are wrong. `Base` <- `Intermediate` <- `Derived`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When cast to a pointer to a derived class, the operand of `dynamic_cast` should be a pointer to a **polymorphic type**, that is a class that declares or inherits a virtual function, while `static_cast` does not have this constraint.

In return, `dynamic_cast` can throw an exception if the operand does not actually point to a subobject of an object of the target type, while `static_cast` leaves it undefined.

Comment: In my origin question, I forgot to add virtual functions (destructors) to the example. I made a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49953172/9600702